# angular app giving mime errors and fails to load on browser after deployed on kubernetes ingress

Tags: angular, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Issue is that my css & js  angular production build files are not getting picked properly , from the browser logs what i understood is that js and cs not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.

Providing screenshot of errors on browser console.

screenshot link below
[image]

[image]

Below is my nginx configuration file

```
server {
  listen 80;

  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index  index.html index.htm;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

  gzip on;
  gzip_min_length 1000;
  gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;


  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

}
```

I have deployed the below ingress yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /test
        backend:
          serviceName: testapp
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /assets
        backend:
          serviceName: testapp
          servicePort: 80
```

What Im trying to achieve is I should be able to load my application on ingress path (/test) , but fails to display . When I try without a ingress path(i.e below), it works properly: could you please help me out what im doing wrong

Comment: The MIME type isn't an error - the file isn't found. It's not clear if `styles.0e****.css` is in `/test` or in `/assets` (when you request it).

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the reply . Actually styles.0e***.css is available in my nginx root folder /usr/share/nginx/html (defined in ngnix.configuration). Its angular ng prod build what iam copying to this location  .and inside that I have assets folder.  for ingress to load the css & js from assets folder , I added a path '/assets' in ingress.yaml .

Comment: The only endpoints you're making available is `/test/*` and `/assets/*` - if you're requesting something that isn't one of those, you're not going to get a result.

Comment: To summarize my angular prod build output files are styles.0e***.css, polyfills.css etc The files are in the same directory as the index.html

Comment: /test/* is mapped to my index.html loacation

Comment: Well, please can you show the full path you're requesting the files that won't load from.

Comment: Exactly, it's `/styles.0e4338761429b4eb16ac.css` and not `/assets/styles.0e4338761429b4eb16ac.css`. Presumably this is your problem?

Comment: is it what you suggest that i need to copy the files located at my index.html to move to assets ?  But then my application should not load when i access 23.96.47.26 . All my files are loading when i access this ip.  when i try to open from my ingress ip its not working

Comment: This is being addresed by having subpath requests in ingress.yaml file for runtimes files and it will  redirect request to backend. Thanks John for helping us

Comment: Can you please wrap it into the answer for the future community reference? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix the issue by changing in tsconfig.json

```
target:'es5'`
```

instead of

```
target:'es2015'`
```

Answer (score -2):

Posting as Community answer to better visibility in future reference. Solution was found based on @John comments.

**Issue:** Cannot connect to resource `styles.0e4338761429b4eb16ac.css`. 
**How resource was requested:** [Nginx-controller-ip]/styles.0e4338761429b4eb16ac.css

OP's Ingress manifest contains 2 endpoints (**/test/***  and **/assets/ ***).

Ingress was looking for file `styles.0e4338761429b4eb16ac.css` in endpoint folders. As it cannot find it (because file was in main folder, not in endpoints) it returned `404 NOT FOUND`.

**Solution:** To reach this file it must be in one of folders from Ingress YAML (as both was reffered to the same service `serviceName: testapp`).